# Casting objects from jsonb to different objects

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, jsonb

I am developing an ASP.NET Core API that uses events with `MediatR` to publish them in the system. I am looking to include a scheduling service to the Api where events are stored in a database and pull out later and published using `MediatR`.

The issue I have is that the objects are stored in the database as `jsonb` and I need to be able to draw them out and cast them to specific object types. I can store the name of the type in the database and access the type that way. However I can't find a solution to this online.

If there is a better way to do this who thing that would be helpful too, but I'm looking for a solution that looks something like this:

```
var eventType = Type.GetType("foo");
var eventObject = obj.ToObject<eventType>();
```

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: See comment below, but MediatR passes an object to a relevant `Handler<T>` method, so we know the type at that point and can perform operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could figure out a way to do this, how exactly do you intend to use `eventObject` after you've managed to create it? Its type is not known at compile time, so you can't write code that uses its methods and properties, because you don't know what methods and properties it has.

For example, if you have a "foo" type with a `DoFoo()` method and a "bar" type with a `DoBar()` method, how do you know whether to call `DoFoo()` or `DoBar()`?

```
var eventType = Type.GetType("foo");
var eventObject = obj.ToObject<eventType>();
eventObject.DoFoo();  //How do you know to do this?
eventObject.DoBar();  //How do you know to do this?
```

The best you can do is a series of if statements:

```
if (eventType) == typeof(foo))
{
    eventObject.DoFoo();
}
if (eventType) == typeof(bar))
{
    eventObject.DoBar();
}
```

Well, if you're going to do that, you may as well cast it in the same if block, which eliminates your problem.

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(foo))
{
    ((foo)obj).DoFoo();
}
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(bar))
{
    ((bar)obj).DoBar();
}
```

If you don't actually need any of its properties or methods, and only need to be able to pass it to some generic method, you can just pass it along as an object. Getting the method is a little tricky though:

```
mediatR.GetType()
    .GetMethod("Publish");
    .MakeGenericMethod(eventType);
    .Invoke(obj, null);
```

Comment: The reason this would work is that MediatR posts the object and looks in the system for a handler of the correct type. So if the type is `Foo` then `mediatR.Publish(foo)` finds the handler `INotificationHandler<Foo>` thus we can be sure of what we have cast the object to.

Comment: I've appended another example to the end of my post that demonstrates how to pass your object to the proper generic method without needing to cast it.